# Remove/change community promotion ad mid year

Tags: support, community-promotion-ads

I'm contemplating to make a community promotion ad which will only be relevant until August this year (it is for a conference).

Will it be possible to either

- withdraw the ad (by deleting the answer to the community promotion ad question on meta?)
- replace the image (by editing the answer to the community promotion ad question on meta?)

after the conference is over?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can freely edit or remove ads after you've posted them. If there's any caching involved, it's fairly short as I haven't noticed any problems before.